# numpy - add two arrays to get matrix

Tags: numpy

How do I find a matrix of all sums of two arrays?

With the input

```
x1 = np.array([0, 1])
x2 = np.array([1,2,3])
```

I want the output of this to be like this:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: Try : `x1[:,None]+x2`.

Comment: @Divakar thanks, that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NumPy's `newaxis` attribute:

```
x1[:, np.newaxis] + x2
```

which is an acronym for `None`:

```
In [2]: np.newaxis is None
Out[2]: True
```

Thus:

```
x1[:, None] + x2
```

also works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `list comprehension`  like this example:

```
x1 = np.array([0, 1])
x2 = np.array([1,2,3])

final = [[j+k for j in x2] for k in x1]

# Or, maybe:
# final = np.array([[j+k for j in x2] for k in x1])
# >>> array([[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]])
```

print(final)

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]
```